# Parse grammar for a member expression

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

What is the correct grammar for a standard member expression?

E.g. the ast from the code:

`test.test.function()`

would be

`MemberExpression("test", MemberExpression("test", MethodCall("function")))`

And likewise for a variable:

`test.test.test.variable`

`MemberExpression("test", MemberExpression("test", MemberExpression("test", Variable("variable"))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the language, surely :-) But it's pretty straight-up in most grammars (see below).

One comment, though. As indicated by the grammars below, member access (like function calls and, usually, subscripting) acts like a postfix operator; the symbol after the dot (or arrow, in C-like languages) is a symbol representing a member name. It is not an expression; the only expression in the member lookup is on the left-hand side of the operator. So `a.b.c` should correspond to an AST node something like:

```
MemberLookup(MemberLookup(Variable("a"), "b"), "c")
```

and `a.b.func(2, c)` should be turned into:

```
MethodCall(MemberLookup(Variable("a"), "b"),
           "func",
           List(Number(2), Variable("c")))
```

or, perhaps,

```
Apply(MemberLookup(MemberLookup(Variable("a"), "b"), "func"),
      List(Number(2), Variable("c"))
```

(The difference has to do with the implicit `self`/`this` argument; there are various strategies for handling this. Contrast Java, Python and Lua for three completely different strategies.)

Anyway, here's a couple of simple grammar fragments:

#### C

Here's an excerpt from the C grammar (as found in Appendix A of the C standard:

`postfix-expression:
  primary-expression
  postfix-expression '[' expression ']'
  postfix-expression '(' argument-expression-listopt ')'
  postfix-expression '.' identifier
  postfix-expression '->' identifier
  postfix-expression '++'
  postfix-expression '--'`

I included more than just the member access functions, because it shows that `.identifier` and `->identifier` are handled just like any other postfix operator, which is a useful insight. The same production also includes two postfix bracketed operators, subscripting (`[...]`) and function call (`(...)`), which seem relevant here. But I left out compound literals (which I would have put into `primary-expression`).

#### Python

The comparable excerpt from the Python 3.9 docs:

`primary:
  primary '.' NAME
  primary '(' [arguments] ')'
  primary '[' slices ']'
  primary genexp
  atom`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Just to clarify in regards to the C grammar, what would the binary operator grammar be in terms of this postfix expressions. Would it be  `postfix-expression + postfix-expression`, or is there a larger grammar group for all expressions including postfix-expression that might be used instead?

Comment: @Tom: the C grammar is usually written in cascading precedence style. C has a lot of precedence levels and each level has its own syntactic variable. The AST doesn't necessarily reflect that; deoending on your preferences, you might have nodes in which the operator is an attribute or different node types for different operators or a combination.

Comment: Anyway, the C grammar is easy to find on the internet.